# PingFederate OGNL expression to CustomDataSource

Tags: ognl, pingfederate

Is it possible to specify OGNL expression as input parameter for custom data store (**CustomDataSourceDriver** implementation)?

PingFederate 7.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no but there's an (unsupported) custom OGNL datasource that can be used as an intermediary datasource to transform attributes in to a form that is useful for your own, consecutive datasource, see: https://code.google.com/p/pingfederate/source/browse/trunk/datasource/ognl/src/com/pingidentity/datasource/OGNLDataSource.java

Comment: Thanks for reply @Hans Z 
As I understand this datasource does not have access to external context (e.g. already defined variables or **#this** object

Comment: it's an OGNL expression that is evaluated in the context of a DataSource, not the regular case - when it is evaluated in the context of an attribute - so #this does not really apply; but you can refer to attribute values by using their key names; which context would you need?

Comment: I need to pass Http Request custom headers to custom data source. I'm retrieving it with #this.get("context.HttpRequest").getObjectValue()...  While this works from SAML attributes fulfillment, I can't find a way to make it work for custom data source.

Comment: You're right, that won't work with a custom DataSource because the HttpServletRequest is not available in the API call to the DataSource. But there may be a better solution for your specific use case by using different adapters and use HTTP header based adapter selection + associated contract fulfillment. May be worth talking to your RSA about it or contact support.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an OGNL expression on an attribute. 
The OGNL expression has access to the HttpRequest. So – you can access all the headers from it.

Have more details in the below post :-
https://guptaashish.com/2016/04/22/pingfederate-include-complex-payload-in-a-saml-assertion/